# How to restrict origin URLs to backend service via Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

My current production setup includes Cloudflare responsible for DNS, then AWS ALB which routes traffic to multiple backend EC2 instances with a dockerized backend stack that includes nginx reverse proxy and multiple replicas of the backend container.
Please find the nginx conf below:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections   1000;
}

http {
    log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
        '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
        '"$http_origin" "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" "$gzip_ratio"';
        
    upstream forms_api {
        server 127.0.0.1:4003;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name subdomain.example.com;
        gzip on;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "https://*.example.com";

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://forms_api;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
        }
    }
}
```

So what I want to implement is that, only certain/relevant origin URLs must be able to access this particular backend service. I want restrict access to origin URLs of the pattern *.example.com. Requests coming in from any other URL or IPs must be restricted. So all these relevant origin services are within the same VPC as this backend service.

I've tried with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header typically used for CORS. But not sure if this is configured correctly too because it's not restricting the access. Also if there is any other efficient method to do it within this current setup of AWS ALB, EC2 instances and nginx reverse proxy, please let me know.